# How to get repeating week dates count between a date range in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I have an array of date-ranges from which I need to know how many people have worked in each week for the whole year.

```
Eg: mainArray = ['01-01-2020','31-12-2020']; //year range

dateRanges = [
  [01-01-2020, 03-01-2020], //week 1
  [03-01-2020, 06-01-2020], //week 1 and 2
  [09-01-2020, 09-01-2020], //week 2
  [10-01-2020, 11-01-2020], //week 2
  [22-01-2020, 23-01-2020], //week 4
  ....
];

//first we need to find all the weeks from the mainArray date-range 

//then calculate the weeks colliding in the dateRanges array.

the output should be =>

workLoadInWeeks = [2,3,0,1,0,0,0,0,......,0];
```

Explanation: 
Since 03-01-2020(date in week-1) is repeating in 1st and 2nd array indexes, that's why the output has 2 as the first value.

Since the dates of week-2 are repeating in dateRanges[1], dateRanges[2], dateRanges[3], that's why the output has 3 as the second value.

since nobody worked in 3rd week its 0 in the output array

Week start - Sunday, 
7 days a week,
I want the week date range to start from the 1st Jan, so first week would be a partial week as 1st start is a Wednesday.

This may sound confusing. I have tried my best to explain.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question. Please let me know if you need any further clarification. Thank you

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-date-exercise-47.php see this can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need [a function which results overall count of week](http:////%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796950/javascript-weeks-per-year):

```
function getISOWeeks(y) {
    var d,
        isLeap;

    d = new Date(y, 0, 1);
    isLeap = new Date(y, 1, 29).getMonth() === 1;

    //check for a Jan 1 that's a Thursday or a leap year that has a
    //Wednesday jan 1. Otherwise it's 52
    return d.getDay() === 4 || isLeap && d.getDay() === 3 ? 53 : 52
}
```

And a function which gets week number:

```
function getWeek(date_string) {
    let [d, M, y] = date_string.split(/[- :]/);
    let passedDate = new Date(y, parseInt(M) - 1, d);
    let onejan = new Date(passedDate.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    week = Math.ceil( (((passedDate - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay() + 1) / 7 );
    return week;
}
```

After we having this weeks we counts of persons per Week. And then we can figure out how many people have worked in each week for the whole year.

```
let weeks = dateRanges.map(s => s.map(d => this.getWeek(d)));

let distinctWeeks = weeks.map(s => 
    s.filter((item, pos) => s.indexOf(item) == pos)).flatMap(s => s);

let personPerWeek = distinctWeeks.reduce((a, c)=> {
    a[c] = a[c] || 0;
    a[c] += 1;
    return a;
},{})

const weekCount = getISOWeeks(2020);
let personsPerWeeks = [];

getWorkWeeks = (workWeeks, weekCount) => {
    for (let index = 1; index <= weekCount; index++) {
        let personCount = personPerWeek[index] || 0;
        workWeeks.push(personCount);
    }
    return workWeeks;
}
```

An example can be seen here:

```js
function getWeek(date_string) {
    let [d, M, y] = date_string.split(/[- :]/);
    let passedDate = new Date(y, parseInt(M) - 1, d);
    let onejan = new Date(passedDate.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    week = Math.ceil( (((passedDate - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay() + 1) / 7 );
    return week;
}

function getISOWeeks(y) {
    var d,
        isLeap;

    d = new Date(y, 0, 1);
    isLeap = new Date(y, 1, 29).getMonth() === 1;
    //check for a Jan 1 that's a Thursday or a leap year that has a
    //Wednesday jan 1. Otherwise it's 52
    return d.getDay() === 4 || isLeap && d.getDay() === 3 ? 53 : 52
}

let dateRanges = [
  ['01-01-2020', '03-01-2020'], //week 1
  ['03-01-2020', '06-01-2020'], //week 1 and 2
  ['09-01-2020', '09-01-2020'], //week 2
  ['10-01-2020', '11-01-2020'], //week 2
  ['22-01-2020', '23-01-2020'], //week 4
];

let weeks = dateRanges.map(s => s.map(d => this.getWeek(d)));
let distinctWeeks = weeks.map(s => s.filter((item, pos) => s.indexOf(item) == pos)).flatMap(s => s);
let personPerWeek = distinctWeeks.reduce((a, c)=> {
    a[c] = a[c] || 0;
    a[c] += 1;
    return a;
},{})

const weekCount = getISOWeeks(2020);
let personsPerWeeks = [];

getWorkWeeks = (workWeeks, weekCount) => {
    for (let index = 1; index <= weekCount; index++) {
        let personCount = personPerWeek[index] || 0;
        workWeeks.push(personCount);
    }
    return workWeeks;
}

getWorkWeeks(personsPerWeeks, weekCount);
console.log(personsPerWeeks)
```

Comment: Genius @StepUp . Damn! this is complicated. Thank you so much . I hope you had fun solving this. 

Comment: @AshikPaul thanks for so kind words! I am glad that it helped to you! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works for you.

```js
dateRanges = [
 ["01-01-2020", "03-01-2020"], //week 1
  ["03-01-2020", "06-01-2020"], //week 1 and 2
  ["09-01-2020", "09-01-2020"], //week 2
  ["10-01-2020", "11-01-2020"], //week 2
  ["22-01-2020", "23-01-2020"], //week 4

];

mainArray = ['01-01-2020','31-12-2020'];
//console.log(dateRanges);
function diff_weeks(dt2, dt1) 
 {

  var diff =(dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) / 1000;
  diff /= (60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
  return Math.abs(Math.round(diff));
  
 }

//for(var i = 0; i< dateRanges.length;i++){
//console.log(dateRanges[i][0]);
  var dateString1 = mainArray[0];
  var dateParts1 = dateString1.split("-"); 
  var dt1 = new Date(+dateParts1[2], dateParts1[1] - 1, +dateParts1[0]); 
  var dateString2 = mainArray[1];
  var dateParts2 = dateString2.split("-"); 
  var dt2 = new Date(+dateParts2[2], dateParts2[1] - 1, +dateParts2[0]); 
  //console.log(dt1);
  console.log(diff_weeks(dt1, dt2) + " Weeks");
//}
```

Comment: Will do, Thank you for the immediate response. I don't have permission to upvote your answer. I will check and let you know. Thank you so much. 

Comment: Welcome. Once you got enough reputation do upvote. Thanks. if this works for you accept too. @AshikPaul

Comment: I am expecting an array as an output which is of length 52(weeks in a year). Please check the sample output.

Comment: code which i added for `mainArray` same thing you can do for other array using for lop. you want that also  ?

Comment: I guess you have not understood the question. Your output is giving me the number of weeks between two dates. But I am expecting the dates repeating in all the week ranges(dateRanges array). I will add more details in the example. Sorry for the confusion.