# Generate a list of commercial weeks falling between 2 dates in Ruby / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, week-number

I am trying to created a list of year-week (equivalent to mySQL's `YEARWEEK(date,1))` falling between two date values in Rails. List is generating perfectly if start-date and end-date are falling in same year. Here is my code:

```
  campaign_start_date = "2013-08-02 06:59:00"
  campaing_end_date = "2013-09-01 06:59:00"

  start_year = DateTime.parse(campaign_start_date).cwyear
  start_week = "%04d%02d" % [start_year, DateTime.parse(campaign_start_date).cweek]

  end_year = DateTime.parse(campaing_end_date).cwyear
  end_week = "%04d%02d" % [end_year, DateTime.parse(campaing_end_date).cweek]

  if start_year == end_year
    (start_week..end_week).each{ |i| result << i }
  else
    # need to build a suitable logic here. to handle the case when duration spans over multiple years. for example started in 01-Nov-14 and ended in 01-May-15
  end

  return result
```

there will be no problem with above date values, it will fall to if case and the result I will get is:

```
[
  "201331",
  "201332",
  "201332",
  "201333",
  "201334",
  "201335"
]
```

which is also what I exactly want. BUT if my start-date and end-date values are these for example:

```
  campaign_start_date = "2014-07-23 06:59:00"
  campaing_end_date = "2015-03-01 06:59:00"
```

means falling in different years, then it need different logic that the one I have in `if` condition because for these date values (`start_week=201430` and `end_week=201509`) the `if` condition is not suitable here because it would generate `80` values, which is wrong because number of weeks between these dates are not `80`. Need help to develop the logic for `else` case. May be its easy but right now I am just tired to dig it any deeper.

*Special attention*: the solutions should care about commercial year and commercial week (refer .cwyear and .cweek functions of rails) For example yearweek of `2016-01-01` would be `201553` not `201601`

any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to those who replied t. I've finally solved the problem like this:

```
  campaign_weeks = []

  campaign_start_date = "2014-07-23 06:59:00" # or any date
  campaing_end_date = "2015-03-01 06:59:00" # or any date

  start_year = DateTime.parse(campaign_start_date).cwyear
  start_cweek_of_the_campaign = "%04d%02d" % [start_year, DateTime.parse(campaign_start_date).cweek]

  end_year = DateTime.parse(campaing_end_date).cwyear
  end_cweek_of_the_campaign = "%04d%02d" % [end_year, DateTime.parse(campaing_end_date).cweek]

  if start_year == end_year
    (start_cweek_of_the_campaign..end_cweek_of_the_campaign).each do |w|
      campaign_weeks << ("%04d%02d" % [start_year, w])
    end
  else
    (start_year..end_year).each do |y|
      first_cweek_number_of_the_year = (y == start_year) ? start_cweek_of_the_campaign : 1
      last_cweek_number_of_the_year = (y == end_year) ? end_cweek_of_the_campaign : DateTime.new(y, 12, 28).cweek
      (first_cweek_number_of_the_year .. last_cweek_number_of_the_year).each do |w|
        campaign_weeks << ("%04d%02d" % [y, w])
      end
    end
  end

  return campaign_weeks
```

Notes: 28th Dec always fall in the last cweek/iso-week of the year. last ISO week of the year is either 52 or 53.

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Last_week

Got some hint from this answer: [Calculating the number of weeks in a year with Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952011/calculating-the-number-of-weeks-in-a-year-with-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck is `(start_week..end_week)` range. It apparently goes through hundred (since we are on decimals):

```
 2014xx ⇒ 201452 ⇒ 201453 ⇒ ... ⇒ 201499 ⇒ 201500 ⇒ ...
```

You should probably filter your range, like:

```
r = (start_week..end_week)
r.to_a.reject { |e| e[-2..-1].to_i > 52 }
```

Depending on how you count weeks (=-based, or 1-based,) the `201500` should be likely filtered as well:/

```
r.to_a.select { |e| e[-2..-1].to_i.between? 1, 52 }
```

Comment: a week may have 53 weeks. like '2016-01-01' is the 53rd week of 2015

Answer (score 0):

Try this out; it will work for any set of dates irrespective of whether the years are the same or not:

```
campaign_start_date = "2014-07-23 06:59:00"
campaign_end_date = "2015-03-01 06:59:00"

start_date = DateTime.parse(campaign_start_date)
end_date = DateTime.parse(campaign_end_date)

while start_date < end_date
  puts "%04d%02d" % [start_date.cw_year, start_date.cweek]
  start_date = start_date + 7.days
end
```

Comment: it won't cares about commercial year and commercial week i.e `.cwyear` and `.cweek`.... for example if date is `2016-01-01` then its year date would be `201553` and not `201601`

Comment: Use the syntax you already had for formatting the output. I updated the answer.

Comment: thanks @prakash, but start date can be any day of the week. like if start date was a Wednesday then 2nd week would not start on (start_date + 7.days). The second week would start on next Monday

Answer (score 0):

A bit late in the discussion but here is what I used to get the number of commercial weeks between two dates:

```
def cweek_diff(start_date, end_date)
  return if end_date < start_date
  cweek_diff = (end_date.cweek - start_date.cweek) + 1
  cwyear_diff = end_date.cwyear - start_date.cwyear
  cyear_diff * 53 + cweek_diff - cwyear_diff
end
```

It worked perfectly in my case. Hope it helps ;)